# WP Elementor Choose Control Prefix Class Prefixed %s String Format

Tags: wordpress, elementor

**I am having trouble with elementor prefix class using with CHOOSE control
Here is code snippet**

```
    $this->add_responsive_control(
        'course_author_layout',
        [
            'label'        => __('Layout', 'text-domain'),
            'type'         => Controls_Manager::CHOOSE,
            'options'      => [
                'left'   => [
                    'title' => __('Left', 'text-domain'),
                    'icon'  => 'fa fa-long-arrow-left',
                ],
                'up' => [
                    'title' => __('Center', 'text-domain'),
                    'icon'  => 'fa fa-long-arrow-up',
                ],
            ],
            'prefix_class' => 'etlms-author-layout-%s',
            'default'      => 'left',
        ]
    );
```

**Problem is here in prefix_class. In the HTML Markup prefix class is showing with %s but there should only show value.**

**Current scenario of class : etlms-author-layout-%sleft**

**Expected result of class : etlms-author-layout-left**

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `%s`, then you will get the expected result.